# Symfony2 PHP 5.4.4 Cannot change the ID of an active session

Tags: php, session, symfony

Currently, we install our web application in Symfony2 and we find a blocking problem.

- linux Debian Wheezy
- PHP 5.4.4
- Symfony version 2.1.10-DEV - app/dev/debug

The fatal error to the exception :

> vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/AbstractProxy.php
>   throw new \LogicException('Cannot change the ID of an active
>   session');

Stack Trace :

> in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 484  -+
>               public function setId($id)
>               {
>                   if ($this->isActive()) {
>                       throw new \LogicException('Cannot change the ID of an active session');
>                   }
>                   session_id($id);
>       at AbstractProxy ->setId ('09g5hbsvg1apk8d32k52l19rr5')
>       in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 208  -+
>       at NativeSessionStorage ->setId ('09g5hbsvg1apk8d32k52l19rr5')
>       in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 780  -+
>       at Session ->setId ('09g5hbsvg1apk8d32k52l19rr5')
>       in /home/wwwmain/www_v5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/EventListener/TestSessionListener.php
>   at line 54  -+
>       at TestSessionListener ->onKernelRequest (object(GetResponseEvent))
>       at call_user_func (array(object(TestSessionListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent))
>       in /home/wwwmain/www_v5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher.php
>   at line 139  -+
>       at ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(array(object(ProfilerListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(TestSessionListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(SessionListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(Firewall), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(RequestListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(TwigExtension2), 'onKernelRequest'),
>   array(object(RequestListener), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request',
>   object(GetResponseEvent))
>       in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 4781  -+
>       at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
>       in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 4999  -+
>       at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
>       in /home/wwwmain/www_v5/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher.php
>   at line 78  -+
>       at ContainerAwareTraceableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1412  -+
>       at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1392  -+
>       at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 1568  -+
>       at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
>       in kernel.root_dir/bootstrap.php.cache at line 619  -+
>       at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
>       in /home/wwwmain/www_v5/web/app_dev.php at line 25  -+

Logs :

> DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\TestSessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
>       CRITICAL - LogicException: Cannot change the ID of an active session (uncaught exception) at
>   /home/wwwmain/www_v5/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 484
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\TestSessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Eyrolles\CompteBundle\Service\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Eyrolles\EcommerceBundle\Twig\Extension\TwigExtension2::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
>       DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".

Any ideas, thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried with a stable version of Symfony?

Comment: Would be also nice to know what you're actually doing (code example please!).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running phpunit tests? If so, then calss TestSessionListener calls Session::setId() if it finds Cookie with session name.

I'm, also encounter this problem. Looks like the only way is to extends this class and override "test.session.listener.class" parameter.